# Curly Brackets in Regex Expression { }

Tags: c#, regex

just want to ask the right expression for curly bracket

output should be all text inside { and ends with } will all be color blue . not a single line but all text inside curly brackets even if its different line .

further more something like this1:

```
int csharp = rtb.SelectionStart;
Regex bracket = new
Regex("\'[^\"]*\'");

foreach (Match brack in bracket.Matches(rtb.Text))
{
    rtb.Select(brack.Index, brack.Length);
    rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
    rtb.SelectionStart = csharp;
    rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
}
```

expression above was for singlequote . all text inside ' ' (sample 'text') will all be color blue . i need for the curly brackets thanks .

> starts with { and ends with }

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but the current regex should be `Regex("\'[^\']*\'");` note that I changed this part `[^\']`. So to convert it to {} you should maybe try `Regex("\{[^}]*\}");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(yourString, @"{[^}]*}");
```